# indentation issue in coffeescript code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am working on a project which uses coffeescript(I am new to this), backbonejs and rails 4.0.0 at the backend. I am making a backbone router class in coffeescript with following code

```
class App.Routers.MainRouter entends Backbone.Router

    routes:
        "": "index"

    index: ->
        console.log "Hello form router"
```

But above code always return following error

[image]

I tried different sort of indentation but it keeps giving me this error. Where am I making mistake and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
class App.Routers.MainRouter entends Backbone.Router
```

to

```
class App.Routers.MainRouter extends Backbone.Router
```

Comment: Whats the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: yours has a typo "entends"